# Merging $t$ arrays of size $t$ cannot be done in $O(t^2)$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, sorting, proof-techniques, recursion

> Dr. John claims that he designed a comparison-based algorithm FastMerge that can merge $t$ arrays of size $t$ at most each in $O(t^2)$ time.  In Dr. John’s own words, ”Given $t$ sorted arrays $B_1,B_2,\dots,B_t$ such that each $B_i$ contains at most $t$ elements, FastMerge will produce a sorted array $B$ that contains all elements of $B_1,\dots,B_t$ in sorted order.  My algorithm works in time $O(t^2)$ for any integer $t$. FastMerge is a comparison-based algorithm.” Prove that the claim of Dr. John is not correct.
>
> Hint: You can use the following fact without proof.  If the function $T(n)$ is specified by a recursion
> $$
> T(n) =
> \begin{cases}
> \sqrt{n} T(\sqrt{n}) + cn & \text{if } n > d, \\ O(1) & \text{if } n \leq d,
> \end{cases}
> $$
> for some constants $c,d$, then $T(n) = O(n\log\log n)$.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: You're  missing a word, it appears. You said "... that can merge $t$ arrays of size at most _____ each in $O(t^2)$ time." Fill in the blank. Oh, welcome to the site, too.

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: @D.W. I'm fairly sure my professor writes his own homework. I thought that the answer was: since the minimum time of a comparison-based sorting algorithm is O(n log n), and there are t^2 elements in the worst case, the best FastMerge could do is O(t^2 log t^2). But then I read the hint, and am completely confused on what to do.

Comment: Great!  If this is from a homework written by your professor, then you can [edit] the question to credit your professor / that homework by name and a link; and you can show your progress and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dr. John's algorithm, you could sort arrays in time $O(n\log\log n)$ (use the hint, choosing the value of $t$ which allows you to apply the hint), and this is a problem (why?).

Comment: @HeapOverflow I'm not providing a complete solution on purpose. However, rest assured that this argument works. There's nothing to "address". This is how you solve the exercise. Perhaps you should give it a try.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I somehow misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I know that the absolute best time complexity for a comparison based algorithm is O(n log n). And since there would be at most t^2 elements total here, sorting would be O(t^2 log t^2). But i'm not sure that's the correct answer because of the hint. I'm just not sure where the T(n) relation actually factors into the problem

Comment: Dr. John's algorithm doesn't sort lists. It merges several sorted lists. You need to use Dr. John's algorithm to produce a sorting algorithm.